# Issue using jquery to Traverse the DOM

Tags: jquery

The data getting returned from the script below is a local full web page, but I keep getting `context: undefined`  am I missing something?  I am just trying to select the body.

```
$.get(URL, function(html) {
    var body = $("body", html);
}, "html");
```

To elaborate a bit more I want the body element of raw HTML I just requested:

```
[prevObject: st.fn.st.init[67], context: undefined, selector: "body", jquery: "1.9.0",     constructor: function…]
context: undefined
length: 0
prevObject: st.fn.st.init[67]
selector: "body"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: jQuery discards `html`, `head` and `body` tags.

Comment: If I can grab the raw HTMl, is there an alternate way to running through and selecting the body element?

Comment: Maybe using string manipulation, but why do you need the `body` tag? attributes? `html` in your code contains html content of the body element. If you need body element's attributes you can store them in a hidden input and select that element instead.

Comment: I need to draw out the body element on canvas.  I just need to select the raw html's body element.